# Solving $4u_{tt}-3u_{xt}-u_{xx}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solving $\begin{cases} 4u_{tt}-3u_{xt}-u_{xx}=0\tag1\\u(x,0)=x^2\quad\text{and}\quad  u_t(x,0)=e^x\end{cases}$ in $\mathbf R\times\mathbf R_{>0}$

First I factorized and get for the first line;

$(\partial_x-4\partial_t)(\partial_x+\partial_t)u=0$ and set $v:=(\partial_x+\partial_t)u$

then $v_x-4v_t=0$ is transport equation with solution $f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}t\right)$

hence  $(1)$ is reduced to $u_x+u_t=f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}t\right)$. This is nonhomogeneous transport equation with solution

$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle\int_0^t f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}t+2(s-t)\right)ds+g(x-t)$$

considering initial conditions I get $g(x)=x^2,\ $ $\ f(x)=e^x-2x$

then wolframalpha yields, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-t)%5E2%20%2B%20integrate%20(e%5E(x%2B1%2F4t%2B2(s-t))%2B2*(x%2B1%2F4t%2B2(s-t)))%20%20with%20respect%20to%20s%20from%200%20to%20t)

but if I apply $(1)$ to the result it is not true, where is the mistake ?

Comment: Couldn't you go from the factorisation to noting that $u$ should be of the form $f(4x+t)+g(x-t)$, and then applying the conditions?

Comment: @πr8 Yes that is another method, I read it somewhere but we didn't treat the classificiation of the pdes (as hyperbolic, elliptic, parabolic) so I think I have to use this

Answer (score 0):

$(\partial_x-4\partial_t)(\partial_x+\partial_t)u=0$ and set $v:=(\partial_x+\partial_t)u$

then $v_x-4v_t=0$ is transport equation with solution $f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}t\right)$

Hence  the problem is reduced to $u_x+u_t=f\left(x+\frac{1}{4}t\right)$.

This is the nonhomogeneous transport equation with solution

$u(x,t)=\int_0^t f(x+s-t+\frac 14 s)ds+g(x-t)\tag{$\star$}$

Initial condition $u(x,0)$ implies $g(x)=x^2$

second initial condition $u_t(x,0)$ yields

$f(x)=e^x+2x$

Inserting in $(\star)$ gives,

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-t)%5E2%20%2B%20integrate%20(e%5E(x%2B5%2F4s-t)%2B2*(x%2B5%2F4s-t))%20%20with%20respect%20to%20s%20from%200%20to%20t)